# Google Maps V3 drag Marker and update PolyLine

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to develop an application where the user draws around a property, it adds a marker and a poly line so they can clearly see what's happening. But I want to add the ability to drag the Marker (this is easy) and update the PolyLine's position (this is not so easy?)

### Here is some of my code

This is the function that *draws my poly lines*.

**the variable *'ll'* is an instance of google.maps.LatLng**

```
// Shorter namespace
    var _g = google.maps;

    // Shorten the namespace, it's used
    // a lot in this function
    var s = SunMaps;

    // If we've reached the max number
    // of lines then exit early.
    if (s.LINES >= 4) {
        return;
    }

    // The defaults
    var options = {
        "strokeColor"   : "green",
        "strokeOpacity" : 1.0,
        "strokeWeight"  : 4
    };

    // If we don't have an instance of poly
    // create one.
    if (s.POLY == false) {
        s.POLY = new _g.Polyline(options);
        s.PATH = s.POLY.getPath();
    }

    // Push the new coords into the path object
    s.PATH.push(ll);

    // Set the map for the poly
    s.POLY.setMap(s.instance);

    // Add a marker
    new s.Marker(ll);

    // Increase the counter
    s.LINES++;
```

**Draws the markers at the same point (the s.Marker function used in the line code)**

**the variable *'ll'* is an instance of google.maps.LatLng**

```
var _g = google.maps;

    // Our custom marker
    var marker = new _g.Marker({
        "position" : ll,
        "icon"     : {
            "path" : _g.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            "scale": 10
        },
        "draggable": true,
        "map"      : SunMaps.instance,
        "LineIndex": SunMaps.LINES
    });

    _g.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (e) {
        console.log(marker.getPosition());
        // Here is where I can't workout or find documentation
        // on how to move the line.
    });
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do [this](http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/v3test/mvc/poly_bind.html) from [this discussion in the Google Maps API v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/169e31356c8ca4cb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So I figured it out. Using @Dave's method

Here is the code that updates the polyLine as you drag the marker

```
    var _g = google.maps;
    var _s = SunMaps;

    // Our custom marker
    var marker = new _g.Marker({
        "position" : ll,
        "icon"     : {
            "path" : _g.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            "scale": 7
        },
        "draggable": true,
        "map"      : _s.instance,
        // This is the last known index of a polyLine
        "lineIndex": _s.LINES
    });

    // Listen to the drag event
    _g.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function (e) {
        // Set the new position of the marker as it drags
        this.setPosition(e.latLng);

        // Update the path
        _s.PATH.setAt(this.lineIndex, this.getPosition());
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The `path` property of the `Polyline` object is an `MVCArray`. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray

So, to move the last point you should be able to do:

```
s.PATH.setAt(s.PATH.getLength() - 1, marker.getPosition());
```